# On-demand Managed Account

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway, payment-processing

I'm wondering if Paypal supports creating account on-demand in Australia.

So currently what we are looking for is creating payment accounts on behalf of our users. The users may not see if the account is actually created by paypal. The accounts then may accept payment and we (as the service provider) may transfer the balance somewhere else on behalf of the user. Additionally the account may only be used couple of times then probably abandoned (or if possible be removed)

We looked up at both the Paypal dev site and Braintree docs but couldn't find any.

Is there any workaround utilising the current paypal (or braintree) service to accommodate such a requirements?